# IPv6 on ASUS WL-520GU or other

Tags: ipv6

It's coming this summer.  [IPv6!!!](http://www.cellstream.com/intranet/genfodder/274-world-ipv6-launch-day-june-6-2012.html)

[This DD-WRT tutorial](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPV6) is information overload for me.  I can't tell if this would be supported on my ASUS WL-520GU, and I don't see a clear way to make it a secure IPv6 installation.

**What is the cheapest & easiest path to IPv6 for a wireless home network?**

Requirements:

1) I'm really only interested in supporting link-local IPv6 traffic at the moment (PRNP experiments).
2)  IPv6 firewall/other protecting private network from outside traffic.  Or just unavailable completely.

I don't want to spend more than $50

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was all wrong.  Here's what I learned for the benefit of others:

1) IPv6 within a private network such as mine (same subnet?  but that's an IPv4 concept, right?) does not require the router to support IPv6 since the Link-Local traffic does not require routing.  As long as the PCs' firewalls are set to allow IPv6 ECHO packets, ping should work.

2) When looking at the IPv6 link-local address in ipconfig, the last part after the / or % symbol is a scope ID.  Pinging a remote machine does not work for me if I include the scope ID, but if I leave it off, it works.

3) My PRNP/Mesh/PeerChannel troubles remain, but only for my windows server 2008 r2 machine.  Windows 7 machines work correctly.  I suspect the lack of "Peer Networking Grouping" service on 2008, but I can't figure out how to install it.